# How to make a POST request that redirects in wordpress?

Tags: html, ajax, wordpress, xmlhttprequest, http-post

It's a POST request with login form data. When I artificially try to make the same request using HTML, then the status code is `200` and it does not redirect, rather reload the login page only. But, from original PHP file, the status code is `302 Found` and then it redirects to the profile page corresponding to the login information.

```
          <form  class="user-registration-form user-registration-form-login login" method="post">
            <div class="ur-form-row">
              <div class="ur-form-grid">
                <p class="user-registration-form-row user-registration-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                  <label for="username">Username or email address <span class="required">*</span></label>                       <input placeholder="" type="text" class="user-registration-Input user-registration-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="username" value="" />
                </p>
                <p class="user-registration-form-row user-registration-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                  <label for="password">Password <span class="required">*</span></label>                        <span class="password-input-group">
                  <input placeholder="" class="user-registration-Input user-registration-Input--text input-text" type="password" name="password" id="password" />
                  </span>
                </p>
                <p class="form-row">
                  <input type="hidden" id="user-registration-login-nonce" name="user-registration-login-nonce" value="00cebd1a11" /><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/my-account/" />                <input type="submit" class="user-registration-Button button" name="login" value="Login" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="" />
                  <label class="user-registration-form__label user-registration-form__label-for-checkbox inline">
                  <input class="user-registration-form__input user-registration-form__input-checkbox" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> <span>Remember me</span>
                  </label>
                </p>
                <p class="user-registration-LostPassword lost_password">
                  <a href="http://localhost/my-account/lost-password/">Lost your password?</a>
                </p>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Please help. Any constructive advice or query or information is warmly welcome. Thanks.

Comment: all web requests use HTTP (not "html").   Can you more clearly explain exactly how you're making the requests in the 2 scenarios?  The browser will automatically folow a 302 redirect, but programmatic access usually does not.  It's sometimes an option so you should share how you make the request from PHP.

Comment: please kindly provide with code sample, so community can easily spot your actual problem. Thanks

Comment: @DanielFarrell So, how can I specify in HTML that I want to redirect to the profile page corresponding to my login info?